# degree of a graph

Tags: r, igraph

I used the following code and created  a graph:-

```
a <- graph.formula(A-D:B:C:E, k-P:J)
```

then i calculated degree of all the nodes using a function of igraph package

```
centralization.degree(a)
```

output was

```
$res
[1] 4 1 1 1 1 2 1 1

 $centralization
 [1] 0.3571429

 $theoretical_max
 [1] 56
```

As one can see 4 is the highest of all therefore i outputted that but i also want the node whose corresponding value of degree is the highest. In the above example it is A. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Check out `degree` in the [igraph manual](http://igraph.org/r/doc/degree.html). Then use some combination of [`which`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html) and [`max`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html).

As for ties:

```
> a <- graph.formula(Z-D:B:C:E,A-D:B:C:E, k-P:J)
> a
IGRAPH UN-- 9 10 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
> degree(a)
Z D B C E A k P J 
4 2 2 2 2 4 2 1 1 
> which(degree(a)==max(degree(a)))
Z A 
1 6 
>
```

The values are indexes. Z at 1, A at 6, in the degree vector.

Answer (score 2):

`centralization.degree` does more than what you need, so as @pbible says, you can just use `degree`:

```
which.max(degree(a))
# A 
# 1
```

Comment: I made a graph in which two nodes were having highest degree but then as well it is printing only A. @Gabor

Comment: try something like `which(degree(a) == max(degree(a)))` it should return the index of the ties.